# why children of FrameLayout are all visible or all invisible?

Tags: android, layout

I have piece of code as follows:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    android.view.LayoutInflater inflater = (android.view.LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    android.widget.FrameLayout fl=(android.widget.FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, null);
    android.view.View l1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,fl);
    android.view.View l2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second,fl);
    l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setContentView(fl);       

    Log.i("     ","l1 visibility: " + String.valueOf(l1.getVisibility()));
    Log.i("     ","l2 visibility: " + String.valueOf(l2.getVisibility()));
```

Both child layouts are VISIBLE and it is ok.
But when I try to set visibility as follows:

```
    l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Both children has GONE visibility, so nothing is visible?
When I set visibility in reverse order:

```
    l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Both children are visible again!
What I do wrong? Why setVisibility() to one child has effect to another (probably all)?

========================= and after 8 hours:

Ok, I found the solution but I still don't know the reason.

Solution is to add views into frame layout by calling addView() instead of passing root param to LayoutInflater.inflate().

After this workaround visibility of each component view changes independently.

I have no idea what is going on with LayoutInflater.inflate().

========================= and after one hour 1:

Shame on me.
LayoutInflater.inflate() returns root view if it is provided as second parameter, so
everytime I set visibility of root layout in first solution.
Everything is ok with LayoutInflater!

Comment: Thank you. You just saved a life here.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving it all to one main.xml layout (with  of `main` and `second`) and then load it with setContentView(R.layout.main) then `findViewById()` and check setting visibility mode.

Comment: But I definitely want them to have designed separately. I would like to get known why it works in such a strange way.

Comment: ok, when I try VISIBLE/GONE test on two buttons lying on my main layout and the main layout is the only layout lying on empty_layout (FramaLayout) it seems to work correctly. I don't know what to think. A bug in Android library?